# How do I keep the Advantages of IQueryable<T> while using ViewModels or DTOs instead of ORM generated Entities?

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, orm

When using Linq-To-SQL or Entity Framework, the DataContext and generated entities provide IQueryable interfaces for deferred execution. It lets me write code like this:

```
public class RPO
{
    DataContext dc;
    public RPO(){ dc = new DataContext(); }
    public IQueryable<Data> ReadData()
    {
        return dc.Data;
    }
}

public class Svc
{
    RPO repository;
    public Svc() { repository = new RPO(): }
    public IQueryable<Data> ReadActiveData() 
    { 
        return repository.ReadData().Where(d => d.IsActive.Equals(true)); 
    }
    public IQueryable<Data> ReadArchiveData() 
    { 
        return repository.ReadData().Where(d => d.IsArchived.Equals(true)); 
    }
}
```

This model falls appart if in the class `Svc` I return `DataModel` instead of `Data` -- how can I keep `IQueryable<T>` as far down the chain as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your SVC layer should never expose IQueryable. What happens then is, it is actually your service consumer who gets to execute your query which is a bad pattern. So service should always expose 
data which is sufficient for the service-user to work ( display) with.

Preferably a IList or a IEnumarable.

Comment: I'm calling it `Svc` its really the bit of code used internally by the true "services" that are part of the public API. It should really be called BusinessServices or something. But I guess that doesnt matter, because you're saying that `IQueryable<T>` should never go past the service layer.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, unless your DTO or ViewModel also implements IQueryable. Once you transform the results into something that isn't IQueryable, that's it.

I know it's considered a bad pattern, but if you need what IQueryable does in that layer of your code, then you should consider just passing that instead of transforming it before that layer.